# Javascript; Server-less retrieving of unread emails with Gmail API

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail-api

Thanks to OAuth2 many APIs are accessible from client side without any server.

I'm trying to do that with the unread emails in Gmail.

With the [OAuth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) it is possible to achieve that.
However my attempts are not successful (see reply).
I wonder if my attempts have been exhaustive and there is no way to achieve my goal or if I looked over a possibility?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The new Gmail API lets you exactly do that;

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

It uses OAuth 2 and a JavaScript wrapper library

Comment: On https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js it states you need: `Python 2.4 or greater (to provide a web server).`

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [Gmail API doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/) there are two ways to access emails:

- using IMAP/SMTP
- calling https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom

Browsers doesn't provide access to TCP to JavaScript and therefore IMAP/SMTP will not help here.

After trying, the server behind https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom doesn't seem to support CORS. So no luck here neither.

Apparently, a server is needed (or something like [packaged apps that gives TCP access](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network.html))